# How to join two results with Spring Data Specification

Tags: java, spring, jpa, join, spring-data

How to join two results in while using Criteriabuilder

I am using CriteriaBuilder where I am using two table Student and StudentResult.

When I am querying my API

http://localhost:8080/student?query=grade:5,lastRollResult%40SUCCESS%23FAILURE

In this case I am able to get the data from `Join results = root.join("lastRollResult", JoinType.INNER);` This is fetching from StudentResult Table.

Similarly when I am passing the null value as lastRollResult I am getting data from `return root.get("lastRunId");` This is fetching from Student Table as there is no result in that so result column is null.

My question is how to join these two result when I am passing any of the enum like success or failure with null.

```
@Override
protected Expression<String> getPath(SearchCriteria criteria, Root<Student> root) {
  if (criteria.getKey().equals("lastRollResult"))  { // codition check null. avoid join. 
    if (!"null".equals(criteria.getValue())) {
      Join results = root.join("lastRollResult", JoinType.INNER);
      return results.get("result");
    } else {
      return root.get("lastRollId");
    }
}
  return root.get(criteria.getKey());
}
```

This is my class definition :

`public abstract class BaseSpecification<M> implements Specification<M>`

Comment: What do you mean by “Java Specification”?

Comment: @BasilBourque this is what I am trying `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;`

Comment: @David may you add also your entities classes?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please edit question by fixing your query API to add more details.

Comment: @AnishB. I have asked a detailed question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597342/how-to-handle-null-value-in-one-to-many-relation-by-using-criteria-builder

Comment: Are you using spring boot or vanilla spring ?

Comment: I am using Spring boot @AnishB.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I ahve asked detailed question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597342/how-to-handle-null-value-in-one-to-many-relation-by-using-criteria-builder

Comment: I do not understanding exactly what you want to achieve. Could you please provide some example result informations? An SQL equivalent would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve conditional join by using `criteriaBuilder.selectCase()` here is an example how you can modify your code -

```
@Override
protected Expression<String> getPath(SearchCriteria criteria, Root<Student> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    if (criteria.getKey().equals("lastRollResult")) {
        Path<Object> lastRollResultPath = root.get("lastRollResult");

        Expression<String> successExpression = criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(lastRollResultPath, EnumResult.SUCCESS), root.join("lastRollResult", JoinType.INNER).get("result"))
                .otherwise((Expression<String>) root.get("lastRollId"));

        Expression<String> failureExpression = criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(lastRollResultPath, EnumResult.FAILURE), root.join("lastRollResult", JoinType.INNER).get("result"))
                .otherwise((Expression<String>) root.get("lastRollId"));

        return criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(lastRollResultPath, EnumResult.SUCCESS), successExpression)
                .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(lastRollResultPath, EnumResult.FAILURE), failureExpression)
                .otherwise((Expression<String>) root.get("lastRollId"));
    }

    return root.get(criteria.getKey());
}
```

In this example I've used `criteriaBuilder.selectCase()` which creates a conditional expression based on `lastRollResult`. If it's success it joins the `lastRollResult` table and get the `result` column otherwise it returns the `lastRollResult` from the `Student` table.

**Make sure to do code adjustment based on your need it's just an example.**